# Creating new user on fresh Dspace Install on Ubuntu

Tags: dspace

I have installed a fresh Dspace on Ubuntu 14.04 server. I can only access the homepage via via xmlui. Going through jspui gives an internal system error . Using the xmlui link when I try to register the first user, I get an error that it is unable to send a mail to my quoted email address. i have even changed the email but I still cannot create the user.

Answer (score 0):

You must configure the server email in the dspace.cfg.